# How to uninstall asunder-casept?

Tags: software-uninstall

I installed `asunder-casept` from the Ubuntu Software Center. When it didn't work I tried to uninstall it but there is no remove option on the Ubuntu Software Center. I tried `sudo apt remove asunder-casept` but it says it is not installed. I discovered that it is installed under snap directories. What is snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"snap" is an additional method of installing/maintaining/removing applications.  To list applications installed via "snap" open a terminal window, and enter the command

```
snap list
```

if you see the application that you wish to remove in the list provided by that command, you can remove the application with

```
snap remove <application-name>
```

for more help with "snap", enter the command `snap` or the command `snap help` or the command `man snap`

Comment: @joe If the answer helped, please mark it as 'accepted' (the little check mark to the left of answer)